# Swift: Cannot get callout accessory to display

Tags: ios, json, mapkit, mkannotation

I've tried multiple ways to get the callout accessory to display on the map annotations, but I don't know where I've gone wrong.

I'm using a JSON file to extract the coordinates.

The same code works on a separate project using hard coded coordinates, so my guess is that it's the way I'm extracting from the JSON file.

ViewController:
https://gist.github.com/daboobakar/0913e6dea94df1f84592d786e3684bcc

Annotations:
https://gist.github.com/daboobakar/6058da2eac5f64914ffdc7cb94eb99a1#file-poiannotations-swift

EDIT: I've added a picture of how it looks at the moment.[image]

Comment: Set a breakpoint at comment "// 5". Does it break? If yes, log `annotationView` and `btn`.

Comment: What should I look out for after setting a breakpoint at comment "//5"? Sorry, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: Does it stop there (is the code actually called)?

Comment: Yeah, it stops there and the line below it, it says Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1.

Comment: @shallowThought This is what it's showing at the bottom: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2f680etn8u5pocd/Screenshot%202016-11-14%2011.58.58.png?dl=0

Comment: Try setting delegate in storyboard. I ran into a same issue